# Aegir Installation - how to get the sender email correct to allow install to pass

Tags: aegir

During the Aegir installation procedure, the

```
sudo apt-get install -y aegir3 aegir-archive-keyring
```

step runs through a series of installation commands that eventually try to send an email from the aegir user to the aegir user.

Depending on my build environment this may work or not depending on whether the the aegir user is set up as a valid email sender.  I already have the sending email squared away with MSMTP and can send email from my command line but the installer seems to always be assuming the sending is aegir@hostname.

It would be very nice if I could figure out how to 1) override the sender in the installation script or 2) set the email address of the aegir user manually via CLI.

You'd think that 2 would be very easy to find on the internet but, believe it has been anything but easy.
Does anyone know how to alter the apt-get install of Aegir to pick up the sender email address from some environment variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in section 7.1 at https://docs.aegirproject.org/install/#7-install-aegir

```
sudo apt install debconf-utils
mkdir -p ~/projects/aegir/core
git clone https://git.drupal.org/project/provision.git ~/projects/aegir/core/provision
echo "aegir3-hostmaster aegir/email string valid@email.com" | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt install aegir3
```